# Multiple INNER JOIN with GROUP BY and Aggregate Function

Tags: sql, database, group-by, sum, inner-join

I'm back with another question. I've been tinkering with this for 1 and a half days now and still no luck. So I have the tables below.

```
Table1
Field1 Field2 Field3 Field4     Field5
DR1    500    ID1    Active     TR1
DR2    250    ID2    Active     TR1
DR3    100    ID1    Active     TR1
DR4    50     ID3    Active     TR1
DR5    50     ID1    Cancelled  TR1
DR6    150    ID1    Active     TR2

Table2
Field1 Field3
ID1    Chris
ID2    John
ID3    Jane

Table3
Field1 Field2
TR1    Shipped  
TR2    Pending
```

I currently can achieve this result.

```
Name   Total
Chris  650    3
John   250    1
Jane   50     1
```

using this sql statement

```
SELECT t2.Field3 as Name , SUM(t1.Field2) as Total
 FROM [Table1] t1 INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.Field3 = t2.Field1
  GROUP BY t2.Field3
```

However, I'd like to achieve this result shown below.

```
Chris 600 2
John  250 1
Jane  50  1
```

I'd like to check Table3 first if it has a 'Shipped' Field2 then it includes everything in Table1 with 'Active' Field4. It should not include 'Cancelled' Field4. And if Table3 has a Field2 of Pending, it should also not include it. I'd appreciate any little help. Thank you.

Comment: You miss something information. What is "3-1-1" ? In your select you query only 2 fields (name and sum). What is 650? by chris: 500+100+50+150 = 800

Comment: You can just add these conditions to your query: WHERE Table1.Field5 = 'TR1' AND Table1.Field4 = 'Active' , of course, before GROUP BY statement

Comment: Oh sorry, 3-1-1 is COUNT(*). @BaBL86

Comment: @wxyz, yes, that is the way to do it, however I cannot do a WHERE condition unless I connect Table3 to Table1 first by doing an INNER JOIN, and right now it's already using 1 INNER JOIN for Table2. I do not know where to put the 2nd INNER JOIN for Table3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you just need to join all the tables required to have the fields needed in the where clause.

And add a `where` clause.

```
SELECT t2.Field3,
       SUM(t1.Field2) as CTotal,
       count(*) as NbItems
FROM Table1 t1 

INNER JOIN Table2 t2
       ON t1.Field3 = t2.Field1
--add a join on Table3
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 
       ON t3.Field1 = t1.Field5 
--add your where clause
WHERE t1.Field4 = 'Active'
AND t3.Field2 <> 'Pending'
GROUP BY t2.Field3
--ORDER BY CTotal DESC
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/481f08/12)

EDIT

For your problem

```
SELCT custInfo.CName, 
Count(*) as TransactionCount, 
SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal 
FROM (TamarawTransaction trans 
INNER JOIN TamarawCustomerInformation custInfo 
    ON trans.CCustomerCode=custInfo.CCustomerCode) 
INNER JOIN TamarawTrip  trip
    ON trans.CTrip=trip.CTrip 

Where trip.CStatus='Finalized' 
AND trans.CStatus='Active' 
GROUP BY custInfo.CName
```

With "weird access join syntax"

```
SELECT TamarawCustomerInformation.CName, 
Count(*) AS TransactionCount, 
SUM(CTotal) AS TransactionTotal
FROM TamarawCustomerInformationn 
INNER JOIN (TamarawTrip INNER JOIN TamarawTransaction ON TamarawTrip.CTrip=TamarawTransaction.CTrip) 
          ON TamarawCustomerInformationn.CCustomerCode=TamarawTransaction.CCustomerCode
WHERE TamarawTrip.CStatus='" & "Shipped" & "' and TamarawTransaction.CStatus='" & "Active" & "'
GROUP BY TamarawCustomerInformation.CName;
```

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for your reply. I already did your statement. Here is my original. Select TamarawCustomerInformation.CName, Count(*) as TransactionCount, SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal from TamarawTransaction INNER JOIN TamarawCustomerInformation ON TamarawTransaction.CCustomerCode=TamarawCustomerInformation.CCustomerCode INNER JOIN TamarawTrip ON TamarawTransaction.CTrip=TamarawTrip.CTrip where TamarawTrip.CStatus='" & "Shipped" & "' and TamarawTransaction.CStatus='" & "Active" & "' GROUP BY TamarawCustomerInformation.CName.    It says syntax error :(

Comment: @chris_techno25 without the where clause, do you have a syntax error ?

Comment: thank you for your patience sir, yeah still syntax error, it says somewhere between the 1st INNER join and the 2nd. I've read w3schools sql syntax lessons and other websites. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my statement. With only 1 INNER JOIN, it works, then I added a 2nd INNER JOIN, now it doesn't work. I thought I should give it a comma, but it's still not working. :(

Comment: Still the same sir :( This is now my statement. "Select TamarawCustomerInformation.CName, Count(*) as TransactionCount, SUM(CTotal) as TransactionTotal from TamarawTransaction T1 INNER JOIN TamarawCustomerInformationn C1 ON T1.CCustomerCode=C1.CCustomerCode INNER JOIN TamarawTrip T2 ON T1.CTrip=T2.CTrip where T2.CStatus='" & "Finalized" & "' and T1.CStatus='" & "Active" & "' GROUP BY C1.CName"

Comment: @chris_techno25 could you give the complete error message ? What's your dbms, by the way ?

Comment: Here's the error sir, "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'T1.CCustomerCode=C1.CCustomerCode INNER JOIN TamarawTrip T2 ON T1.CTrip=T2.CTrip'." I use Access for development while I use Microsoft SQL Server upon deployment. I just use the migrate tool and change the connection string and the date query format. Thank you very much.

Comment: @chris_techno25 I think you must add some round brackets with access. Can you test my edited query (second one) ?

Comment: I already tried using parenthesis a few hours ago and they didn't work. I'm running out of combinations. I tried your statement just now and still no luck :( Thank you for helping. Do you have anymore ideas? I know your code works. I think it's a problem with Access.

Comment: @chris_techno25 I made a try in access, the last one seems to work !

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for helping, I really appreciate it. I tried your code. Now it gives me another error which is "Syntax error in JOIN operation." I used your code edited a bit. I used TamarawCustomerInformation instead of TamarawCustomerInformationn which is of course a typo. That's it. :( I hope I'm not bothering you too much sir, I never ask questions unless I've spent too much time on something without even a bit of luck :(

Comment: I got it to work sir, I changed your code a bit and finally after 25 minutes working on SQL view in access. Thank you very much for your help. One last request, can you explain your code a bit on how you got that structure? Coz I honestly don't get the structure. Your very first code suggestion was exactly what I had in mind and I tried it only to get a syntax error. Now you got me a code that works but I dont understand it. Considering SQL's statement formatting standard, we both arrived at solution 1, which unfortunately doesn't work. Thank you :)

Comment: @chris_techno25 Sorry, but I also can't explain why Access does work that way. The join syntax is really counter-intuitive for me too. But... that's how Access work !

Comment: well you SIR just made my day. Thank you very much. Kudos!